# Using multiple stored procedures to populate one table in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I would like structure of my SSRS report to look like the following:

```
| Size | BuldingAmount | BuldingAmount | HouseAmount | HouseCount |
```

The fields Size, BuildingAmount and BuildingCount are to be populated from stored procedure `GetCityFinancialDetails`. This stored procedure returns a table that looks like this:

```
| Size | BuildingAmount | BuildingCount |
```

The fields HouseAmount and HouseCount are to be populated from stored procedure `GetHouseFinancialDetails`. This stored procedure returns a table that looks like this:

```
| Size | HouseAmount | HouseCount |
```

Both stored procedures will return results grouped by `Size` which can be one of the following for both `City` and `House`:

- Small
- Medium
- Large

I am wondering how I can logically group these results into a single table via SSRS? How can I group the Building Amount and Building Count size with its associated City House size?

Answer (score 0):

A tablix in SSRS can only have 1 source of data (dataset), if you have access to the SQL for the two stored procedure you could write a new stored procedure that combines them with a JOIN and use this new 3rd stored procedure to run the report.

The other option is that you could place a sub report within the tablix or use a lookup set.

Take a look at the following links, they may help

[Two datasets inside a same tablix](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f30ff0d2-ba37-4bb8-b0a0-a6e06b3273fd/two-datasets-inside-a-same-tablix?forum=sqlreportingservices)

[MSDN - Assigning two data sets to one table in ssrs](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2e6dfb5a-2de2-4d2f-96e5-4cb94543c6ec/asigning-two-data-sets-to-one-table-in-ssrs)

Hope this helps.